# What I should buy to replace metal weather stripping?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

We have this really old metal weatherstrips on our front door, its sharp, broken and overall sucks.  No idea what to replace it with but looking for something high quality, long lasting, and effective.

[Album](https://imgur.com/a/IdyfxEG)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

The inclination might be to install something foamy or rubbery to "modernize" the situation. That rarely works well. In order for your door to operate easily such a seal needs to *give*--to readily compress when the door closes. Long runs of foam tape or rubber bead tend to not, resulting in a hard bang upon closure, or just requiring a lot of force. That may be ok for a door you rarely use, but it'll quickly become burdensome in a primary access door. Such solutions also require that your door be hung very well--any twist or skew will leave their performance lacking.

This is why most modern doors have a flat foam strip in a V shape which can *bend* to create a seal, reducing operation force and accommodating imperfect gaps. You may be able to find such a product designed for retrofit, but most such factory-installed strips engage a channel cut into the door jamb specifically for them. I'm not sure retrofit versions exist.

Therefore, I actually recommend replacing your spring steel seals with... spring steel seals. They're available at better-stocked hardware stores, and they'll do a reasonably good job of blocking airflow without impeding door operation. You can also replace the sweep a the bottom with a similar one, refreshing the rubber seal and the appearance.

Beyond that, consider a new door.

Comment: Thank you, this might be the best solution but when I search "Spring Steel Seals" it doesnt really bring up what I expected.  Are there other names for it?

Comment: That was my descriptive term. Try "metal weather stripping", just as in your title.